# Angular Firebase authentication state always return null

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I tried to create anonymous login to firebase in my ionic app.
here is my authentication service.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    public authState: any = null;
    public UserId: any;

    constructor(public angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private firestoreUser: FirestoreUserProvider) {
        this.angularFireAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
            this.authState = auth
            if (this.authState)
                this.UserId = this.authState.uid;
        });
    }

    get isUserAnonymousLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return (this.authState !== null) ? this.authState.isAnonymous : false
    }

    get currentUserId(): string {
        return (this.authState !== null) ? this.authState.uid : '';
    }

    anonymousLogin() {
        return this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInAnonymously()
            .then((user) => {
                this.authState = user;
                this.updateUserData(user.uid);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    signOut(): void {
        this.angularFireAuth.auth.signOut();
    }

    updateUserData(UserId: any): void {
        this.firestoreUser.createUser(UserId);
    }
}
```

While try to login the below code works fine, but the page refreshes and login page is shown again.

```
  this.authService.angularFireAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
          if (!user) {
            console.log('user is not logged in!');
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(AnonymousLoginPage)
          }
        })
```

Means the subscribe method always return null. Any help?

Comment: try `.switchMap((data) => { console.log(data); } ` instead of subscribe

Comment: https://github.com/codediodeio/ionic-firestarter/blob/master/src/providers/auth/auth.ts